# Gallery just showing plain short code like [gallery ids="240,236,275"]. how to solve this?

Tags: posts, gallery

I've followed this codex [The WordPress Gallery](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_WordPress_Gallery)

after I added the gallery when see just plain text like [gallery ids="240,236,275"]

the sample page : [gallery page](http://www.gsecanopy.com/3003blog/test-gal/)

I did not add any filter or something for this on my `function.php`
Do I want to add anything for that?

How can I solve this..?
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that your theme has not been setup for post formats.

Comment: I've created my own theme and design. so how can I post format for the theme?

Comment: To add post formats is not difficult, but it means template changes. I would advice you to do online searches and find good quality tutorials about post formats. Also don't forget to use the wordpress codex. Wordpress is shipped with default themes that already have build in post formats. You can use them as examples when creating your templates. You don't need to include all post formats, just the ones you need, also the same with the content-postformat.php files. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Please check that the shortcode you have added in content is proper, check that you might have miss any thing in it.

If your shortcode is ok then it seems that post content is loaded as it is without applying shortcodes. So you need to apply do_shortcode() function for content.

Please add following code in your theme's function.php file.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'apply_short_code' );

function apply_short_code( $content ) {

    if ( is_single() && in_the_loop() && is_main_query() ) { // add this condition if you want to apply this for selected pages only.
        return do_shortcode($content) .
    }

   return $content;
}
```

If you have added shortcode in custom fields(other than default content section), you need to apply `do_shortcode` funtion before you print the value of that field.

Hope this will help you.